# Using a bot to post a message to Slack

Tags: php, api, permissions, slack, slack-api

I have a slack instance where I'm the only user (so far). I'm attempting to post a simple "hello world" message using the bot account so the message does not show up as coming from my account.

```
$url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xoxb-XXXXXX&channel=general&text=hello%20world";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$head = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch);
```

When I post using the `xoxp-XXXX` oAuth token it works great, except that it comes from my account. When I post using the `xoxb-XXXX` token, I receive a `"error": "not_in_channel"` reply. And I've received `chat:write:user` user scope error - though I've granted all 50 permissions to my app.

How do I set my slack application to allow this write to occur from the bot account on the application rather than from my account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple.

1. Your bot needs the `bot` scope as a bot user.
2. Ensure you are using the `bot access token`
3. Invite the bot to join the channel

Comment: Morning Caleb, I see that too. I've added all of the scopes - gave the bot user every access, but yet the error persists.

Comment: @SAL Try inviting the bot to join the channel

Comment: Thanks - that totally did the trick. I assumed the bot had access to the channel when I set up the channel it could post to. Really appreciate it. Simple answers are the best ones!

Comment: @SAL Happy to help